# how can i access the android cam by porting ubuntu os in android mobile through opencv-python

Tags: android, python, opencv, porting

I want to access android cam instead of developing an app of my Opencv python code.so i have ported the Ubuntu Os in android and installed Opencv python in Ubuntu and through Cv2 module tried to access cam . 
but both work on different environment . is there a solution for this.